# Elasticsearch + C# Why I get after Client.Indices.Create() a second and unassigned index?

Tags: c#, elasticsearch

I create a index on Elasticsearch with the C# code below.
But instead of creating one assigned index I find a second unassigned index with the same name. I don't want and need this second (unassigned) index. My elasticsearch.yml has standard content, i have not made any changes (see below).

**What could course the second (unassigned) index respectively how can I avoid it?**

```
ElasticClient.Indices.Create("1234.attachments", c => c
    .Settings(s => s
        .Analysis(a => a
            .Analyzers(ad => ad
                .Custom("windows_path_hierarchy_analyzer", ca => ca
                    .Tokenizer("windows_path_hierarchy_tokenizer")
                )
            )
            .Tokenizers(t => t
                .PathHierarchy("windows_path_hierarchy_tokenizer", ph => ph
                    .Delimiter('\\')
                )
                .NGram("ngram_tokenizer", td => td
                    .MinGram(3)
                    .MaxGram(3)
                    .TokenChars(
                        TokenChar.Letter,
                        TokenChar.Digit,
                        TokenChar.Symbol)
                )
            )

        )
    )
    .Map<ElasticDocument>(mp => mp
        .AutoMap()
        .Properties(ps => ps
            .Text(s => s
                .Name(n => n.Doname)
                .Analyzer("windows_path_hierarchy_analyzer")
            )
            .Object<Attachment>(a => a
                .Name(n => n.Attachment)
                .AutoMap()
            )
        )
    )
);
```

Kibana:

GET _cat/shards?v=true&h=index,shard,prirep,state,node,unassigned.reason&s=state

[image]

elasticsearch.yml:

```
# ======================== Elasticsearch Configuration =========================
#
# NOTE: Elasticsearch comes with reasonable defaults for most settings.
#       Before you set out to tweak and tune the configuration, make sure you
#       understand what are you trying to accomplish and the consequences.
#
# The primary way of configuring a node is via this file. This template lists
# the most important settings you may want to configure for a production cluster.
#
# Please consult the documentation for further information on configuration options:
# https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/index.html
#
# ---------------------------------- Cluster -----------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for your cluster:
#
#cluster.name: my-application
#
# ------------------------------------ Node ------------------------------------
#
# Use a descriptive name for the node:
#
#node.name: node-1
#
# Add custom attributes to the node:
#
#node.attr.rack: r1
#
# ----------------------------------- Paths ------------------------------------
#
# Path to directory where to store the data (separate multiple locations by comma):
#
#path.data: /path/to/data
#
# Path to log files:
#
#path.logs: /path/to/logs
#
# ----------------------------------- Memory -----------------------------------
#
# Lock the memory on startup:
#
#bootstrap.memory_lock: true
#
# Make sure that the heap size is set to about half the memory available
# on the system and that the owner of the process is allowed to use this
# limit.
#
# Elasticsearch performs poorly when the system is swapping the memory.
#
# ---------------------------------- Network -----------------------------------
#
# By default Elasticsearch is only accessible on localhost. Set a different
# address here to expose this node on the network:
#
#network.host: 192.168.0.1
#
# By default Elasticsearch listens for HTTP traffic on the first free port it
# finds starting at 9200. Set a specific HTTP port here:
#
#http.port: 9200
#
# For more information, consult the network module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Discovery ----------------------------------
#
# Pass an initial list of hosts to perform discovery when this node is started:
# The default list of hosts is ["127.0.0.1", "[::1]"]
#
#discovery.seed_hosts: ["host1", "host2"]
#
# Bootstrap the cluster using an initial set of master-eligible nodes:
#
#cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["node-1", "node-2"]
#
# For more information, consult the discovery and cluster formation module documentation.
#
# --------------------------------- Readiness ----------------------------------
#
# Enable an unauthenticated TCP readiness endpoint on localhost
#
#readiness.port: 9399
#
# ---------------------------------- Various -----------------------------------
#
# Allow wildcard deletion of indices:
#
#action.destructive_requires_name: false

#----------------------- BEGIN SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -----------------------
#
# The following settings, TLS certificates, and keys have been automatically      
# generated to configure Elasticsearch security features on 16-03-2023 07:16:50
#
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

# Enable security features
xpack.security.enabled: true

xpack.security.enrollment.enabled: true

# Enable encryption for HTTP API client connections, such as Kibana, Logstash, and Agents
xpack.security.http.ssl:
  enabled: true
  keystore.path: certs/http.p12

# Enable encryption and mutual authentication between cluster nodes
xpack.security.transport.ssl:
  enabled: true
  verification_mode: certificate
  keystore.path: certs/transport.p12
  truststore.path: certs/transport.p12
# Create a new cluster with the current node only
# Additional nodes can still join the cluster later
cluster.initial_master_nodes: ["FM11L"]

# Allow HTTP API connections from anywhere
# Connections are encrypted and require user authentication
http.host: 0.0.0.0

# Allow other nodes to join the cluster from anywhere
# Connections are encrypted and mutually authenticated
#transport.host: 0.0.0.0

#----------------------- END SECURITY AUTO CONFIGURATION -------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

I figure out that the reason is that by default a replica will be set. But there is no second node, where the shard is assigned to.

So I have to set the number of replicas to 0.

```
            ElasticClient.Indices.Create(InstanceIndex, c => c
            .Settings(s => s
                .NumberOfReplicas(0)
                ...
```